# How to find the angle in between two triangles when one of them is the double of the other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> Using the figure from below find $x$

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The problem is as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&60^{\circ}\\
2.&40^{\circ}\\
3.&60^{\circ}\\
4.&70^{\circ}\\
5.&30^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

This peculiar problem is confusing to me, what sort of identity can be used to solve this?. The only thing which I could spot there was:

$\beta+2x+\theta=180$

But that's it. I don't know what other relation can be established from the given information. Can someone help me here?. **Please include a drawing in your answer** as it becomes difficult for me to read from only algebraic expressions. Please be the most descriptive as possible and it would help me a lot to have a step-by-step solution as I am struggling with this figure.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note that we have $2x+\beta + \theta = \pi$. Notice that $\angle BDF+\angle CEG = \pi - \angle DAE = \pi - x$. Notice that the sum of the angles of $\triangle BDF$ and $\triangle CEG$ is $2\pi$: $2(\beta+\theta)+\gamma+\phi+\pi-x=2\pi$. Note that the sum of the angles of $\triangle AFG$ is $\pi$, so $2\pi-2(\gamma + \phi)+x=\pi$ Using these 3 equations we derived:
$$ $2(\beta+\theta)+\gamma+\phi+\pi-x=2\pi$$
$$2x+\beta + \theta = \pi$$
$$2\pi-2(\gamma + \phi)+x=\pi$$
We can find $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$. (Substitute $y=\beta+\theta,z=\gamma+\phi$, you have three equations and three variables)

Comment: Your answer is not displaying correctly. Other than that I'm still stuck. Does it exist another way to solve this problem without using three system of equations?. This was intended to be solved using angles formed by notable lines in a triangle. Could this approach be used?.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell It's displaying correctly from me: https://i.ibb.co/s2PxWWk/image.png

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell There are usually many ways to solve a geometry problem. You could make my solution to a one-liner angle chasing if you want.